# Prove $a_n < 2^n$ using strong induction

Tags: induction

Prove: $a_n < 2^n$ for all $n\ge 1$

$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3},\quad n\ge4$

$a_1=1 , a_2=2 , a_3=3$

Comment: Hint: If $n\ge 4$, indeed already earlier, $2^n\gt 2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you can provide a proper induction basis, so I'll leave that to you.

Using strong induction, our *induction hypothesis* becomes:

- Suppose that $a_k<2^k$, for all $k\leq n$.

In the *induction step* we look at $a_{n+1}$. We write it out using our recursive formula and see that: 
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}.$$ Now by the *induction hypothesis* we know that:

- $a_n<2^n$,
- $a_{n-1}<2^{n-1}$, and
- $a_{n-2}<2^{n-2}$.

So $a_{n+1}<2^n+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}$. Some basic airithmetic will lead to the final statement now.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but I don't think $2^{n+1} = 2^n + 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2}$ if you could finalize the proof I'll greatly appreciate it

Comment: @ph-quiett I never claimed that $2^{n+1}=2^n+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}$. Please read carefully what needs to be proven.